# What is the difference between Rank and specifying [,] in an array?

Tags: c#

In .NET, there is a Rank property for arrays.

What is the difference between this and specifiying something like:

int[,] intArray = new int[3,3]; ?

Which would be of Rank 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Rank property is read-only. It is part of the type of the array and can only be set when the array is created. The expression `int[,]` refers to the type of rank 2 integer arrays, and you can create a rank 2 array either with the `new int[n,m]` syntax or with the `Array.CreateInstance` static method.